# Why is the last statement false? (edx)

Tags: python, edx

```
a = [1,2,3] 

b = a
a == b
True
a is b
True 

b = a[:]
a == b
True
a is b
False
```

Why is the last statement false?
"b = a[:]" What is the difference of the line from the other line?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `==` and `is`? In any case `b = a` simply creates a new reference to the same list. `a[:]` is a slice of a list, which creates a new list object. In effect, since it is a whole slice, it creates a copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a[:]` makes a shallow copy of `a` meaning that `b` is a new list and is not the same as `a` (but the inner elements if `a` was a 2d list would be the same)

If you did:

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
b = a[:]
b is a
>>> False
b[0] is a[0] 
>>> True
```